# unable to simulate a click with win32api in bluestacks 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32con

I just tried a normal leftclick function.

```
def leftClick(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    time.sleep(.1)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
```

Set cursor position works fine. But left down/up doesn't work.

Comment: It looks okay to me. More information about any errors you are getting or more code you have related to this would be helpful. As of right now, the only thing I can think of to recommend is potentially trying `pyautogui` instead. Import it, then use `pyautogui.click(x, y)` and report back.

Comment: Basically, I forgot that the program being automated was open with administrative privileges.
So it is not possible for win32api to access the admin window without having these rights.